# How to input an Image and its corresponding value (.csv) to a Regression model in python?

Tags: python, image, csv, tensorflow, regression

I have a dataset of images and a .csv file which contains the name of these images together with some value (ranging from 1-5) associated with each of the images. 
e.g dataset of images, and the value gives the amount of rainfall, ranging from 1(lowest)-5(highest). The values can even be fractional eg 2.5.

I have already developed a model for image classification, where I rounded off the image values and divided the whole dataset into 5 classes and input the 5 folders to the model.

```
|data folder1 (training)

 |train_data_dir

  |class1
   |image1.jpg
   |..
   | image100.jpg

  |class2
   |image1.jpg
   |..
   | image100.jpg

  |class5
   |image1.jpg
   |..
   | image100.jpg

|data folder2 (test) similar as above


*model description*
 x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)<br>
 x = Dropout(0.5)(x) <br>
 ... 

 *train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,   target_size=(img_height, img_width), batch_size=batch_size, class_mode="categorical")*
```

Now I want to design a regression model for the same problem.
I want to know how to input the image (eg image.jpeg) and its corresponding value (saved in data.csv) file and send it as input to the neural network?

```
|data folder1 (training)

 |images folder
   |image1.jpg
   |..
   | image500.jpg

 |data.csv
   |image name
   |rainfall amount (1-5) including fractions

|data folder2 (test) similar as above
```

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you try and clarify it and provide sample images and CSV file so people can get a better idea what you are trying to do please? Will the answer be a flowchart? A shell script? A picture?

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks, i hope the question is clearer now

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to load images from a training set via generator for training a TensorFlow model. You're almost there on the methodology, but you're perhaps not quite understanding the [implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#load_using_keraspreprocessing). TensorFlow expects the following directory structure when using `flow_from_directory`:

```
|-data
  |-train
    |-class_1
      |-img1.png
      |-img2.png
    |-class_2
      |-img1.png
      |-img2.png
  |-test
    |-img1.png
    |-img2.png
```

As you can see, this particular implementation expects a class. To my knowledge, it's not suited for a regression task. However, you may be able to accomplish this with the `flow_from_dataframe` method that's fairly analogous. You will need to construct a pandas DataFrame with one column referencing file paths and another referencing your regression targets. Your generator would be approximately:

```
train_data_gen = image_generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train_df,
                                                     x_col='filename',
                                                     y_col='regression_val',
                                                     batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                     shuffle=True,
                                                     target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH))
```

Comment: Thanks.. I have edited the question again.. Can u make the answer cleared now.